# IO.File.Exists() always returns false

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Consider the following code in Button1_Click

```
Dim stFile as String = IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "uploads/text/file1.txt")
If IO.File.Exists(stFile) Then
    ' Do some processing
End If
```

Exists always returns false in the above code block

And here is Button2_Click code block

```
Dim stFile as String = IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "uploads/text/file1.txt")
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.txt")
Response.TransmitFile(stFile)
Response.Flush()
End If
```

This always downloads the same file. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `stFile`, use the debugger

Comment: If `uploads` folder is in the root directory of you project then simply use this: `Dim stFile as String = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/text/file1.txt")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also crumbled with this issue a while ago and found that the use of "/" and special chars may produce this scenario.

Path.Combine always returns paths with "\".

Try changing `uploads/text/file1.txt` to `uploads\text\file1.txt`

If you are generating dynamic file names then try to avoid including any special characters which may require url encoding such as `%`, `(`, `[space]` etc.

(*Some concepts may seem illogical in this post but using the combination of \, / and special chars wasted almost 8-10 hours of mine*)